# call different functions randomly on page load using jquery

Tags: jquery, random

i have six function like `scan1()`,`scan2()`...`scan6()`. each function loads different images. now i want to call functions randomly on each time page loads.

for example
page load first time, call `sacn4()`

page load second time, call `scan6()`

page load third time, call `scan1()`

and so on

page load i mean page refresh/reload.

or help me in this code i am trying

```
var arr = ['scan1()', 'scan2()', 'scan3()'];
var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1

$(document).ready(arr[ran]);
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var arr = [scan1, scan2, scan3],
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length),
        func = arr[rand];

    func();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
var arr = [scan1, scan2, scan3];
var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1

$(document).ready(arr[ran]());
```

You need to populate your array with function objects, rather than strings containing the names of the functions. On the final line, when you say:

```
arr[ran]()
```

you retrieve a function from the array and then invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359910/1225328):

```
$(function() {
    var arr = ['scan1', 'scan2', 'scan3'];
    var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    window[arr[ran]]();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions are stored in your global object, so you don't need to store them in the array as `'functionName()'`, but rather as `'functionName'`. Then call using `call()` or `apply()`.

```
var arr = ['scan1', 'scan2', 'scan3'];
var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1

$(document).ready(window[arr[ran]].call(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your code, what you want to do can be done in a more simple approach, you dont need 6 functions one for each image, create just one `scan()` function, this function will have an array containing all images and then select one randomly, like this:

```
function scan() {
    var images = ['im1.jpg','im2.jpg','im3.jpg','im4.jpg','im5.jpg','im6.jpg'];
    var inumber = Math.floor((Math.random()* images.length)+1);

    var random_image = images[inumber-1];

    //Do whatever you want with random_image
    alert( random_image ); //Shows the random image
}
```

as a plus, with above code, you can even in the future add more images to the `images` array and they will be automatically included in the randomly selection.

With the above code, your `document.ready` will just be:

```
$(document).ready( scan() );
```

Comment: nice solution but my scenario is a little different .. but i got it.. thanks